# Business Layer Facade vs Mingled Business Components

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, architecture, n-tier-architecture

I'm currently designing the foundation for a large application.  We are going with the traditional 3 tier system using EF in the data layer, plain jane c# classes in the business layer and MVC / WCF for the ui layer.  We have prototyped enough of the application to realize that this will work for us, however due to the complexity of the business requirements **it will be common for some of the business components interact with one another.**

Consider the following two business components:

- RetailManager - Deal with everything related to retail in the system
- CartManager - Deals with everything related to the shopping cart experience

The two interact, for instance, during the checkout process when an item is purchased.  The inventory for the purchased item needs to be reduced.

Here is my thought process so far:

1. Let business components reference each other and ensure cyclical references never happen (CartManager references RetailManager, but never the other way).  "Checkout" would be a method on the CartManager class, and it would call a method on the RetailManager to adjust inventory.  While this will work, I'm not sure how well it will scale, and what the maintenance cost will be over time.  It doesn't feel 100% "right" to me.
2. Create a Facade between the business components and the UI tier.  In this example, the Facade would have the checkout method and a reference to both managers.  I like this approach more than the first, however I know that not all of my business objects will need a Facade, and I don't want to create a ton of Facade classes just to have empty pass through methods.

I'm leaning towards 2, with the caveat that I will only create facade classes where needed.  The UI tier will have access to both the Facade and the business layer components and will have to know when to use which (the only part I don't like about this solution).

I've done a lot of research but haven't been able to come to come up with a solution that feels completely right.

Any thoughts on using the facade pattern in this way, or other ideas to solve the problem are welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you considered a DDD approach? [Correct use of Aggregate Roots](http://dddcommunity.org/library/vernon_2011)

Comment: Yes and no.  Thanks for the reference I'll give it a good read.  I can say that our business objects are what we consider aggregate roots for our domain.  That being said, I need to brush up on DDD principles.

Comment: Take a look at this article http://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=91

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would tend to go with facade implementation.

I would first ask myself, whose responsibility is it to make sure that inventory is reduced when a checkout happens? I don't think it is responsibility of `CartManager` to reduce the inventory. I would have a third class (in your case facade) that makes sure that whenever an item is checked out by `CartManager`, corresponding item is reduced from inventory.

Another option I would consider is event based implementation. `CartManager` would raise a `ItemCheckedOut` event whenever an item is checked out. `RetailManager` would subscribe to this event and would reduce the inventory whenever an event is raised. If you are new to event driven design, follow this question on quora - http://www.quora.com/What-are-some-good-resources-on-event-driven-software-design

Comment: I would agree it's not the responsibility of the CartManager.  I'm leaning towards what you described in your first paragraph.  I have a high level understanding of event driven design but little practical knowledge of using it.  I'll check out your link, thanks.

Comment: I'm thinking through the event based implementation.  Let's say `CartManager` raises the `ItemCheckedOut` event.  How / where should `RetailManager` subscribe to that event?  My thought is during application startup (similar to setting up an IoC container), but wouldn't that imply that there is some instance of `RetailManager` stored somewhere just waiting?  I guess I could create some `EventController` to listen to events and spawn instances of whatever manager is needed to handle it.

Comment: You right, in the simplest implementation you would need an event listener which would find out the types who have subscribed for the event and just create their instance and pass on the event to the instance. I would not use a pre-created single instance as that may lead to weird problems

Comment: I'll probably end up doing a mix of what you said originally.  `Manager` classes will expose core functionality.  They will raise events where necessary that other managers can subscribe to so I can accomplish cause and affect relationships.  I can also see creating facade classes here and there to accomplish larger coordinated workflow type tasks.  The UI layer will have access to Managers & any Facade classes and can choose what it wants to do.

Answer (score 2):

That's a typical problem for using manager/service classes. they always tend to get bloated. When you come to that point it's probably better to start using commands instead.

The great thing since you are using an IoC is that you doesn't have to refactor all the code directly, but can do it when there is time. Simply start writing commands for all new features while keeping the old architecture for everything else.

Here is a intro to commands: http://blog.gauffin.org/2012/10/writing-decoupled-and-scalable-applications-2/

And an intro to my own framework: http://blog.gauffin.org/2012/10/introducing-griffin-decoupled/

Comment: But please note that the command based architecture also works well without any framework.

Comment: I like the idea behind this approach, however I don't want to have to, as you put it "Trick the user", or "Distract the user".  Needing to do that smells of forcing a design pattern in a place where it doesn't fit.  Let's say the user has clicked a button to remove an item from a shopping cart.  Using the command approach, I would fire off a command to do that and redirect back to the cart summary screen.  How can I guarantee that the command completed prior to showing the user the summary screen?

Comment: Why would you use a command for removing a shopping cart item? Use a command to dispatch the order. `Thank you for purchasing. You'll receive a confirmation email soon`.

Comment: You would use such a command if the user wants to delete an item from their cart.

Comment: I would not save a shopping cart until it's completed, but just keep it in a cookie. There are always several ways to solve the same problem. Always trying to use the same approach is more of a design small. imho having to handle the limitation of not being able to return anything from a command is not. It's a price you have to pay to be flexible. When invoking a command you should have done all you can to make sure that it will succeed. imho the user do not care if he get an error one minute later or directly when it's something that he can't help anyway.

Comment: That answer is simply dancing around the issue. It's a core business requirement in our domain that a shopping cart can be shared by multiple users over an extended period of time, which means persisting it to the DB makes sense.  This is where the pattern breaks down.  Not all business operations (at least in our domain) can work asynchronously.  Some operations **need** to be synchronous, such as this one.  I do not **ever** want a user to try to delete an item from their cart, only to see that their request was not fulfilled.

Comment: Well. I don't know your specific requirements, do? So I can just answer in general, right? You need to decide for yourself how you should do. Treating commands as async is just one way of doing it.

Comment: Thanks for your insight, it's been very valuable and helpful.  It has lead me to believe that there is a hybrid approach.  Now to figure out what that is...

Comment: Use commands, but don't make them async. You'll get feedback directly, but still be more decoupled than managers.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19352/discussion-between-rick-b-and-jgauffin)

Answer (score 0):

I personally like the pattern of [CQRS](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html), it fits naturally with other architerural patterns 
such as [Event Sourcing](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventSourcing.html) and suited to complex domains.

Comment: -1 Looks like you are just throwing out buzz words since you fail to mention why those patterns would work in this case. imho CQRS would just make things more complex in this case. CQS on the other hand would probably help making things easier.

Comment: I think OP is looking for other option rather than facade approach for inter-components communication. There is not much detail I could explain those pattern could work in this case but CQRS/CQS would worth to explore.

Comment: I looked into CQRS quite a bit yesterday.  It was worth exploring but I don't think we'll go to that level of change.  +1 for the suggestion, just not 100% what I'm looking for.