# Dependency Injection Architectural Design - Service classes circular references

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, circular-dependency

I have the following service classes:

```
public class JobService {
  private UserService us;

  public JobService (UserService us) {
    this.us = us;
  }

  public void addJob(Job job) {
    // needs to make a call to user service to update some user info
    // similar dependency to the deleteUser method
  }
}

public class UserService {
  private JobService js;
  public UserService(JobService js) {
    this.js = js;
  }

  public void deleteUser(User u) {
    using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope()) {
      List<IJob> jobs = jobService.findAllByUser(u.Id);
      foreach (IJob job in jobs) {
        js.deleteJob(job);
      }
      userDao.delete(user);
      scope.Complete();
    }
  }
}
```

Each of these service classes is getting instantiated by IoC container, and there is not a functional problem, but this to me feels like there is a potential design flaw in this approach and I'm wondering if there's an alternative approach that makes more sense.

Comment: This is one of the reasons why I like property based DI over constructor based DI.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As someone already pointed out, the problem is not with limitations to the DI container but with your design.

I see the reason that you have a separate `UserService` and a `JobService` which contain a reference to each other. This is because both `UserService`  and `JobService` contain some logic that needs the other service as a reference (adding a job requires adding a user, etc.). However, I think that you should NOT reference one service from the other. Rather, you should have another layer of abstraction behind the services which the services will use for the common logic. So, the services will contain the logic which can't(shouldn't) be reused and the helpers will contain the shared logic.

For example:

```
    public class UserHelper{
      //add all your common methods here
    }
    public class JobService {
      private UserHelper us;

      public JobService (UserHelper us) {
        this.us = us;
      }

      public void addJob(Job job) {
 // calls helper class
      }
    }

    public class UserService {

      public UserService(UserHelper js) {
        this.js = js;
      }

      public void deleteUser(User u) {
        // calls helper class
      }
    }
```

In this way, you won't have any issues with circular references and you will have one place which contains the logic which needs to be reused by different services.

Also, I prefer having services which are completely isolated from one another.

Comment: Your concept is solid here, however I generally think of "Helper" classes as classes that don't interact with the persistence layer at all.  Is there some other concept/term that people generally use that sits above the service layer that calls services? Usually that's just my client.

Comment: @AdamLevitt, for me as well, usually that is my client. And I agree, the "helper" classes are a bit awkward to be used to communicate with the persistence layer. Another possibility for that would be to call the different service methods from the client. So, for example, a controller (web app) would first call the user service and then the job service. That kinda breaks the atomic nature of the services though because one service will not be responsible for the whole operation which is performed (adding a user with a job). However, I think I prefer that instead of the circular dependency.

Comment: I think I'm just going to create another third Service and do my very best to come up with an adjective that describes it properly.  I'm noticing the UserService only has a single place where it refers to the JobService --> on signup.  I'm considering MembershipService.

Comment: @AdamLevitt, I would consider the latter approach (calling the different services from the client) in case you might ever need to, for example, add a user without adding a job to it. In this case, you would want to be able to call the user service without having a reference to the job service at all. Also, in my previous comment the term "atomic" is not used very accurately I think.

Comment: Yeah, I think I prefer this direction the best... I'm upvoting your comments :)  I'm glad my question fostered such discussion.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you are having has in fact nothing to do with the limitations of your DI container, but it is a general problem. Even without any container, it will be impossible to create those types:

```
var job = new JobService([what goes here???]);
var user = new UserService(job);
```

The general answer is therefore to promote one of the dependencies to a property. This will break the dependency cycle:

```
var job = new JobService();
var user = new UserService(job);

// Use property injection
job.User = user;
```

Prevent however from using more properties than strictly needed. These dependency cycles should be pretty rare and makes it much harder to either wire your types together, or to validate the DI configuration for correctness. Constructor injection makes this much more easy.

Comment: Agreed... this is just a general design problem.  What's a good pattern to overcome this?

Comment: @AdamLevitt: I don't think there is a general design pattern for this. Look closely at your design if the cyclic dependency is really needed. You could for perhaps extract a new class out of the existing classes that both classes depend on. Or you can wire things together like [explained here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13459780/chaining-layers-with-ioc-setting-lower-callback-to-upper-and-avoid-circular-ref).

Comment: I'm looking really hard and there truly is a dependency.  I'm debating pulling the calls out into a newly created service class, but I'm having trouble making sense of it.

Comment: Generally constructor injection should be prefered to property injection. http://www.fascinatedwithsoftware.com/blog/post/2012/02/01/Prefer-Constructor-Injection-Over-Property-Injection.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You can decouple the services by using events. Instead of calling a dependent method of another service when an action has been performed, an event is raised. An integrator can then wire up the services through the events. A service does not even know the existence of the other service.

```
public class JobService
{
    public event Action<User, Job> JobAdded;

    public void AddJob(User user, Job job)
    {
        //TODO: Add job.
        // Fire event
        if (JobAdded != null) JobAdded(user, job);
    }

    internal void DeleteJobs(int userID)
    {
        //TODO: Delete jobs
    }
}

public class UserService
{
    public event Action<User> UserDeleted;

    public void DeleteUser(User u)
    {
        //TODO: Delete User.
        // Fire event
        if (UserDeleted != null) UserDeleted(u);
    }

    public void UpdateUser(User user, Job job)
    {
        //TODO: Update user
    }
}
```

The integrator wires up the services

```
public static class Services
{
    public static JobService JobService { get; private set; }
    public static UserService UserService { get; private set; }

    static Services( )
    {
        JobService = new JobService();
        UserService = new UserService();

        JobService.JobAdded += JobService_JobAdded;
        UserService.UserDeleted += UserService_UserDeleted;
    }

    private static void UserService_UserDeleted(User user)
    {
        JobService.DeleteJobs(user.ID);
    }

    private static void JobService_JobAdded(User user, Job job)
    {
        UserService.UpdateUser(user, job);
    }
}
```

(Note: I simplified event raising a bit. It's not thread safe like this. But you can assume that the events are subscribed in advance and will not be changed later.)

Comment: Hmm... this is *very* interesting.  What would make this thread safe?

Comment: Also, where would a client call the integrator here?

Comment: The problem is that between testing `if (UserDeleted != null)` and actually calling the event, another thread could unsubscribe the event. So you would assign it to a variable first (this works since events are immutable). `var eh = UserDeleted; if (eh != null) eh(...);`

Comment: @AdamLevitt: I changed the `Integrator` class to a static `Services` class with a static constructor doing the initialization automatically and making the service instances public. The previous class was just intended to show the wire-up, not to be a real-world class.

Answer (score 1):

This wont work in Autofac. See [circular dependencies](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/CircularDependencies) section of the documentation.

> **Constructor/Constructor Dependencies** Two types with circular
>   constructor dependencies are not supported. You will get an exception
>   when you try to resolve types registered in this manner.

You could potentially use [relationship types](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/RelationshipTypes) (`Func<>`, `Lazy<>`) to break the cycle.

Your code is a bit too generic to come up with a proper solution but you should consider changing the direction of dependencies regardless of what IoC container you use.

```
public class JobService {
  private UserService us;

  public JobService (UserService us) {
    this.us = us;
  }

  public void addJob(Job job) {
    // needs to make a call to user service to update some user info
  }
}

public class UserService {
  private JobService js;
  public UserService(Func<JobService> jsFactory) {
    this.js = jsFactory(this);
  }

  public void deleteUser(User u) {
    // needs to call the job service to delete all the user's jobs
  }
}
```

Alternatively, In the case of your example you could move `deleteUser` and create a method, delete all jobs on the job service and instead of refering to the user use an id. this breaks the dependency by using the id.

Another alternative is to pass the job service as a parameter to `deleteUser`.

Comment: I'm wondering if callbacks make sense as a solution, the issue is I have my work all being done in a single transaction scope.

Comment: What are you talking about?

Comment: Let me make an edit to my original post to make it a little more concrete.

Comment: Dave, in reference to your last comment, the key is that I need to ENSURE that when a User is deleted, that ALL of their jobs are deleted before the user is, in order to maintain data integrity.  That's where I'm struggling to remove the UserService's dependency on the JobService.  I'll put some implementation code above to make it even clearer.

Comment: Another alternative is to pass the job service as a parameter to deleteUser <<--- now that's probably the best suggestion so far.

Comment: @AdamLevitt: Consider using cascading deletes in your database: `ALTER TABLE Job
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_job_user
FOREIGN KEY (userID)
REFERENCES User (userID)
ON DELETE CASCADE;`

Comment: Will this cause transactional rollbacks on a failed delete? I'm hoping yes?

Comment: Also, is there a way to force in a history record here with the cascade at the database level?